# Android ConnectivityManager onAvailable sometime not returned

Tags: android, android-connectivitymanager

We use the Android `ConnectivityManager` to listen for internet connection changes inside our app as follows.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        ConnectionStateMonitor().enable(this)
    }

    class ConnectionStateMonitor : NetworkCallback() {
        private val networkRequest: NetworkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI).build()

        fun enable(context: Context) {
            val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, this)
        }

        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onAvailable ")
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
            super.onLost(network)
            Log.i(TAG, "onLost ")
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation is working well except for two issues we've encountered

1. If we connect to the internet by using both wifi and mobile data and turn off wifi sometimes the `onLost()` callback is fired followed by `onAvailable()`, as expected, but in other instances **only** `onLost()` is fired which is incorrect.
2. If we don't have internet connection and open the app `onLost()` is not fired, however if we have internet connection and open the app `onAvailable()` is fired.

Any help, suggestions, workarounds or another approaches to detect internet connection changes reliably would really be appreciated.

Tested on Xioami A2 (Android 9), OnePlus (Android 9)

**DEMO project**
https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidNetworkChangeReceiver

Comment: Did you find an approach to solve your second issue?

Comment: No, I cannot find the answer so I remove this feature from my app. i still look for solution

Answer (score 3):

I have used your project and I added another method: `onCapabilitiesChanged`. I started with the flight mode ebabled and then I turned off and then on again. These are the logs:

> onAvailable 632
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 632 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onAvailable 632
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 632 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onAvailable 632
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 632 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 632 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 632 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onAvailable 633
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 633 [ Transports: WIFI ...] onAvailable 633
>   onCapabilitiesChanged 633 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onAvailable 633
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 633 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 633 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 633 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 633 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 633 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 633 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onLost 632
>
> onLost 632
>
> onLost 632
>
> onLost 633
>
> onLost 633
>
> onLost 633
>
> onAvailable 634
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 634 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onAvailable 634
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 634 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onAvailable 634
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 634 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 634 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 634 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 634 [ Transports: CELLULAR ...]
>
> onAvailable 635
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 635 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onAvailable 635
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 635 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onAvailable 635
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 635 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 635 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 635 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 635 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onLost 634
>
> onLost 634
>
> onLost 634
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 635 [ Transports: WIFI ...]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 635 [ Transports: WIFI ...]

As you can see the `LOST` is for the cellular transport while the `AVAILABLE` is for the `WiFi`

Following your use case (enable wifi, enable mobiledata, disable wifi data, enable wifi, disable wifi) this is what I get.

> onAvailable 640
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 640 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onAvailable 640
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 640 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 640 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 640 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 640 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 640 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onLost 640
>
> onLost 640
>
> onAvailable 641
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 641 [ Transports: CELLULAR ... ]
>
> onAvailable 641
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 641 [ Transports: CELLULAR ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 641 [ Transports: CELLULAR ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 641 [ Transports: CELLULAR ... ]
>
> onAvailable 642
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 642 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onAvailable 642
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 642 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 642 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 642 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 642 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 642 [ Transports: WIFI ... ]
>
> onLost 641
>
> onLost 641
>
> onLost 642
>
> onLost 642
>
> onAvailable 643
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 643 [ Transports: CELLULAR ... ]
>
> onAvailable 643
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 643 [ Transports: CELLULAR ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 643 [ Transports: CELLULAR ... ]
>
> onCapabilitiesChanged 643 [ Transports: CELLULAR ... ]

Comment: Thank you for your testing. I read your log 3 times but still can not understand. Currently, if you have android 9 device, you can test again few time like this `enable wifi, enable mobiledata, disable wifi data, enable wifi, disable wifi // normally onAvaiable not called here). You can try it few times and you will see problem. In my android 8 device, everything work well but I am not sure about all android 8 work well or not

Comment: It called onAvailable for the cellular network for me: every time I turned the Wifi off (even the last time). I'm using a Samsung Note 8 with Android 9.

Comment: Trying again I didn't get the onLost for the cellular when I turned the Wifi on, and then I didn't get the onAvailable when I turned it off.

Comment: `onCapabilitiesChanged ` should do the trick. I also had similar problem, and by adding check for valid internet `networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                    && networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)` helped

Answer (score 2):

The callback should look like this:

```kotlin
val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    private val availableNetworks: MutableSet<Network> = HashSet()

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
        val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
        val hasInternetCapability =
            networkCapabilities?.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)

        if (hasInternetCapability == true) {
            availableNetworks.add(network)
            sendNetworkState()
        }
    }

    override fun onLost(network: Network) {
        availableNetworks.remove(network)
        sendNetworkState()
    }

    private fun sendNetworkState() {
        if (availableNetworks.isNotEmpty()) {
            // TODO: Notify the Internet connection is available
        } else {
            // TODO: Notify the Internet connection is unavailable
        }
    }
}
```

Registering the callback:

```kotlin
val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
    .build()

connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, callback)
```

#### Explanation

`onLost` is called per each network that was previously passed to `onAvailable`, according to the documentation:

> If the callback was registered with registerNetworkCallback() it will be called for each network which no longer satisfies the criteria of the callback.

This also possible that the `onAvailable` will be called twice before the `onLost`

The code was originally found here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=To9aHYD5OVk

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast receiver definition on AndroidManifest has changed a bit. You can find appropriate description on [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring).

You have already implemented this way but anyhow I would like add [Network callback class references](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) as a reference point.

Comment: I read your source on github and found your main idea is checking internet status each 5s. If it is correct, I feel like it not very good for performance. Is there any way to optimization? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi Linh, I can understand your concerns ok then I will update the context of answer may be you can find another solution on developer.android.com .

Comment: Yes, actually listen internet connection change just a litle bit improvement for my application. If it consume too much battery I think I don't need to put it inside because it don't have too much benefit. Now I already remove this feature from my application :D, just when call API and there is no internet, I show error :v

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to use `requestNetwork` instead of `registerNetworkCallback`.

Comment: This wouldn't change anything related to onAvailable. The only difference in behavior between the two is that `requestNetwork` will keep a network up for your app while `registerNetworkCallback` will not. I.e., if no apps have open `requestNetwork` requests for a particular network, `ConnectivityService` will tear it down. It doesn't care about any `registerNetworkCallback` type requests however for this.